# How to get the totale size of all databases

Tags: mysql, group-by, rollup

Hi i'm trying to get the totale size of all my databases in GB

I started with this command its work well of each one by one but i couldn't get the totale of all databases !!

any idea how how to get the totale size of all databases on final.

this my command

```
mysql> SELECT table_schema AS "Database name", SUM(ROUND(((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024 /1024 ), 2)) AS "Size (GB)" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` option.

```
mysql> SELECT table_schema AS "Database name", 
  SUM(ROUND(((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024 /1024 ), 2)) AS "Size (GB)" 
  FROM information_schema.TABLES 
  GROUP BY table_schema WITH ROLLUP;
```

Read about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using this query:

```
$db->executeSQL("SELECT table_schema, SUM((data_length+index_length)) AS BytesUsed FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='$DBName'");
$db_size = $db->arrayedResult[0]['BytesUsed'];
echo "calculating DB: $DBName - size: " . $db_size . "\n";
```

and for display:

```
/**
 * format size to Kb, Mb, Gb format
 *
 * @param $size
 * @return string
 */
public static function formatSize($size)
{
    $units = explode(' ', 'B KB MB GB TB PB');
    $mod = 1024;
    for ($i = 0; $size >= $mod; $i++)
    {
        $size /= $mod;
    }
    $endIndex = strpos($size, ".") + 3;

    $ret = substr($size, 0, $endIndex) . ' ' . $units[$i];
    return $ret;
}
```